# impala time in Hue UI

Tags: hadoop, hue, impala

I am trying to Estimate the time required by queries from simple to complex in Impala and using the Hue UI. Will it be possible to know the time needed to complete the query through the UI.

Answer (score 2):

Impala or Hive only provides a general estimate of progress.

Hue could try to display an end time by extrapolating the start time by the current progress. Feel free to follow https://issues.cloudera.org/browse/HUE-1219.

Answer (score 0):

Although it seems to be not possible with Hue UI but in Command Shell its the last result line whenever query is completed.

Answer (score 0):

HUE has no such feature in its present version.

You can design a script like:

echo Current time $(date '+%T')

impala-shell -f <> 
OR
impala-shell -q <>

echo Current time $(date '+%T')

and execute the script

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to deamon Web UI (default port 25000) you can navigate to /queries and choose profile for the query you are interested in. Then look for the query time line.