# How to find time it takes for query to execute in Impala?

Tags: hive, impala, hue, bigdata

I am running Impala query on Hue. I want to know the execution time of each Impala query. I looked over different answers on the Internet, but I could not figure out.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [impala time in Hue UI](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18408064/impala-time-in-hue-ui)

Comment: But, there is not best solution. So, if we can suggest better alternative it would be great help for me. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

impala service runs on 25000 port, there you can see all the queries and the time of execution. for quickstart node, example url is: quickstart.cloudera:25000/queries